# Does view.postscript() allow you to call functions loaded as output scripts?

Tags: xpages

I am using `<xpScriptBlock>` to store the contents of two rather long client side functions that loads an ExtJS grid.   I can call the function using clientside javascript just fine.

I discovered that I need to show a different grid based on a condition in the underlining document.  To reference the backend I moved the code to serverside and then tried to call the grid using view.postScript.  This does not work and is the basis of my question.

Is this approach even possible?   I do not wish to put all the code into the event.  The functions are quite long and better kept in a script block for readability and maintainability.  The functions are definitely loaded in the client, as I can manually load them using the firebug console.   Perhaps I am missing something simple so I wanted to ask before changing my approach.

```
var typePO = document1.getItemValueString("typePO");
if(typePO == "AFS"){
    view.postScript("loadGridAFS();")
} else {
    view.postScript("loadGridOther();")
}
```

This code is in the serverside onClientLoad event of a panel.   I have tried adding the 'return' keyword and it makes no difference.

UPDATE:  I can't even get simple alerts to work using view.postscript().  Does this method only work in certain types of events in SSJS???

Comment: Can you define "does not work"? Do errors show up in the browser console? Or does nothing happen? Or does it run but something behaves differently than expected?

Comment: Sure Tim, nothing shows up on the page where the grid should be.  Firebug reports no errors.  It is like the code isn't even there.

Comment: I moved the code from the panel event to the xpage afterPageLoad event and it works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting using a simple alert I can say that view.postScript() does NOT work everywhere.

For a test, I put the same code in an six event of the xpage.   Here is an example of the code I used:  view.postScript("alert('onClientLoad');"); I just changed the message to match the event.

Here are the results:

1. onClientLoad = nothing
2. beforePageLoad = XSP error
3. afterPageLoad = WORKS!
4. afterRestoreView = nothing
5. beforeRenderResponse = WORKS!
6. afterRenderResponse = nothing

I haven't tried every available event out there, but the bottom line here is that you shouldn't count on view.postscript() to work everywhere.  And if it does do nothing, try a simple alert first to see of the event supports view.postscript before questioning the client javascript code you are attempting to run.

Comment: When you consider that the `render_response` phase of the lifecycle sends the markup to the browser, it makes sense that any code intended to affect that markup would have no effect if run during `afterRenderResponse`: it's too late. `beforePageLoad` is too early because the component tree doesn't exist yet. Not sure why it wouldn't work in the other events, but probably for similar reasons.