# Parameter in view.postScript

Tags: xpages

I visit this [website](http://johnjardin.ukuvuma.co.za/2012/12/18/xpages-tip-use-postscript-to-launch-links-in-own-window-from-ssjs/) to learn to use postscript in xpages. I follow the example to run the code and it runs property.

Then I begin to try other way. I use a computed field that use @DbLookup and a button that will use view.postScript to open xpage in a new window. When @DbLookup returns the value, that value will be the parameter in view.postScipt.

When I run the code, it returns error said Java method 'postScript(Array)' on java class 'com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx2' not found

I get confuse about the error since it mentions it is java error and I don't have java code in the xpage.

I think the reason I get the error is the computed field returns more than one value.

However if I hard code values, it run fine

```
var myparam = "Test,Test2,Test3";
```

Or

```
var myparam = "Test"+"Test2"+"Test3";
```

Please find the code for your review please.(It includes the code that cause error, my attempts and the error message)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
//use @DbLookup to find value, that value will be the parameter in  postScript
var value = @DbLookup(@DbName(), "myView", keyword, 3);
return value;
}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var myparam = getComponent("computedField1").getValue();//does not work
//var myparam = "Test,Test2,Test3"; //works
//var myparam = "Test"+"Test2"+"Test3"; //works
//var myparam = "Test"; //(original) works
var myurl = @LeftBack(context.getUrl(),"/") + "/testpostscript.xsp?id="+myparam;
//error occurs in this code
//Java method 'postScript(Array)' on java class 'com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx2' not found
view.postScript("window.open('" + myurl + "')");}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:br></xp:br>
</xp:view>
```

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408733/does-view-postscript-allow-you-to-call-functions-loaded-as-output-scripts) and it seems different to my question.

When I search "postScript(Array) xpages" on the Internet, I don't find much information about it.

So my question is how to let view.postScript runs when the parameter contains multiple values?

Grateful for your advice please. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that the result of your @DbLookup returns more than one value (an array). That's why you see the underlying Java error that postScript(Array) is an unknown method. The postScript method expects a String as input.

I will suggest that you use @Implode() to join the result from the @DbLookup:

```
<xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                var myparam = @Implode(getComponent("computedField1").getValue(); ",")
                var myurl = @LeftBack(context.getUrl(),"/") + "/testpostscript.xsp?id="+myparam;
                view.postScript("window.open('" + myurl + "')");}]]>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```